# GCP terraform service accounts keys export

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

I am having a problem with GCP and terraform.

The problem:
Through a terraform project I want to create a service account, create a key for it and share that key to someone that has to do something with it.
For example, the service account has the objectCreator role on a bucket and whoever has the service account key should be able to write on that bucket.

The problem is:
I can create the service account, the key, etc.. but I cannot find a way to write the keys in a JSON file as the well-known command does:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create KEY_FILE \
    --iam-account=SA_NAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

thanks in advance.

Comment: The real question is: why do you need a service account key file?

Comment: Where is the Terraform code that you wrote that demonstrates a problem and that you made an effort to solve your problem? Please start by reading this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Terraform can create a local file. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by printing it to a file as suggested.

```
resource "local_file" "myaccountjson" {
content     = base64decode(google_service_account_key.sa-name.private_key)
filename = "${var.path}buckets-external-access-identity-sa.json"
```

}